# Sliding page transition like http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, jquery-waypoints

Today I stumbled upon this site : http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints
I love the way they do the page transition when you click on the top menu. It seems to move
the whole body not just some div like I have seen before.

I would like to know how they do it or if there is any ready-made jquery plugin?
Thank in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a set of `div`s that *move*. Not the whole body. If you're confused with the scroller and think it's the page moving, this is done with css `overflow:scroll` at each `div` group.